# Improving ArcGIS Pro performance on virtual desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, performance, virtual-machine

I use ArcGIS Pro remotely and use a virtual desktop. I noticed the software works extremely slowly and would take time to load changes on my map. I took a look at the CPU and memory utilization. My CPU is under an extreme heavy load, as well as my memory. There is no additional software opened up while working with ArcGIS Pro.

Does anyone have any suggestions to have better performance?

PC Specs
Processor: 2-cores 2.10Hz
RAM: 16GB
x64-based processor

Comment: What are the specs of this virtual desktop?  Do you have at least 24-32GiB of RAM?  What speed is the CPU? Please [Edit] the Question.

Comment: How are you up to GPU in your virtualized env?

Comment: @YogeshChavan For virtual desktops, I do not think my workplace provides a competitive GPU. Please think of my computer as a typical office computer.

Comment: You seem to be 2 CPUs, 1Ghz, 8GiB RAM, and GPU support short of make-weight.

Comment: What organization are you in ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Virtualizing ArcGIS Pro - Resources](https://community.esri.com/t5/implementing-arcgis-blog/virtualizing-arcgis-pro-resources/ba-p/1187018/jump-to/first-unread-message) blog post is currently the best starting point to learn about many aspects of using ArcGIS Pro in virtualized environments:

> For the past several years, the Architecture Practice team in
> Professional Services in partnership with the Performance Team in
> Product Development have been writing various articles to assist the
> community to plan, design and deploy ArcGIS Pro in virtualized
> environments. This purpose of this post is to present a single
> resource for the related resources and will be updated as new posts
> are created.